# Is it possible to change parallax during the game using Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

I've added a parallax images to the game in `onLoad` method of the Game class. How to change the parallax images during the game or other parameters, like speed of parallax images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `ParallaxComponent` called `component` you can change the layers by modifying `component.parallax.layers`.

> How to change the parallax images during the game

`component.parallax.layers[i] = <a new parallax layer with a new image>`

> or other parameters, like speed of parallax images?

`component.parallax.layers[i].velocityMultiplier.setValues(x, y);`

If you want to speed up the whole parallax but keep the same multiplier on the different layers you can set `component.parallax.baseVelocity` instead.